# Why should you use a Development Provisioning Profile before an Ad Hoc Distribution Provisioning Profile?

Tags: ios, share, provisioning-profile, beta, ad-hoc-distribution

As an individual developer, why should I go through the trouble of creating a Development Provisioning Profile?

If I want to install my app on my devices and share it with close friends to test it out, doesn't it make more sense to go straight for the Distribution Provisioning Profile (Ad Hoc)?

Comment: For every AdHoc build I do, I perform potentially hundreds of development builds. I can't imagine never doing a development build.

Comment: I guess I should of specified I'm developing an Adobe AIR app, so I'm able to debug most of the errors / crashes on the desktop first before I even transfer it over the iOS devices. I find that most errors that are only occuring on the device can usually be narrowed down by using some on-screen traces / logging output. So an Ad Hoc build sounds like it would be totally reasonable to use and spend less time and effort creating "CertificateSigningRequest" files, uploading and downloading the files that Apple spits back out, etc. It's just such a long irritating process!

Comment: Yeah, that's a pretty important bit of info (using Adobe AIR).

Comment: @bigp its a long irritating process for the first few times. Once you have been through this process a few times, its not irritating at all :)

Answer (score 2):

Who is saying dev provisioning profile is compulsory?

You dont have to use dev provisioning profile.

Adhoc is meant for passing it around for testing purposes.

if you want to step through the code and see how/where the app crashes etc, then you need to use the dev profile. (because some bugs can never be identified on the simulator)

Otherwise ADHoc is good enough.

Comment: Ok, so there's nothing wrong with first testing the app as an Ad Hoc build, and if everything works fine it can be submitted to the App Store without ever building it for a dev provisioning profile?

Comment: if you can get the app the not crash at all, then yeah. fyi: I have never worked on an app that didnt crash at some point the first time it ran on a device. (I dont think you not having a development provisionig profile is considered during the app review, but I am not sure.)